# Can I create a form field in Access which selects from items in the same table?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a database for a list of items stored in our office. Some of the items are physically located inside a box, bag or another container, so to describe this situation I have one record for the "Box" item, and a separate record for any and all items inside the box. Here's an example:

```
+--------+--------------+-------------+----------+
| ItemID |     Item     | ContainerID | Quantity |
+--------+--------------+-------------+----------+
|      1 | Box          |             |        1 |
|      2 | Notebook     |           1 |        3 |
|      3 | Pencil case  |           1 |        2 |
|      4 | Shopping bag |             |        1 |
|      5 | Paper plate  |           4 |       10 |
+--------+--------------+-------------+----------+
```

So, the box contains 3 notebooks and 2 pencil cases, the bag contains 10 paper plates, etc.

I have a lot of items to input, and I want to create a form that will make the process easier. Currently I have to go into datasheet view and look up the number for the ItemID I want to reference. If I use a form to enter data, I'll have to either know the ID for the particular container item, or look it up every time.

What would be ideal is if I could click on a drop-down menu and select from a list of all the items already inputted, and when I select the item, it fills in the ID of the Item for the ContainerID field. It would be even idealler if the drop-down menu was ordered with the most recently input item at the top.

Is this possible to implement without VBA?

Comment: Yes. You can use a Form in datasheet view (looks like a table) and use it as subform on another form. The main form can contain a combobox with ordered containers (create a query for this `SELECT ItemID, Item FROM TheTable WHERE ContainerID IS NULL ORDER BY Item`). In the AfterUpdate event of the ComboBox, set a filter in the subform.

Comment: Thanks - do you think you could put that in an answer with a bit more detail?

Comment: This question has the potential to degenerate into a tutorial. StackOverflow is for questions on specific problems. Your question very broad.

Comment: This is a specific problem, which you proved when you answered it with a specific solution. Because you put your answer in a comment, I'm asking if you could put it into an answer so I could accept it, and give it a bit more detail so it's clear for myself and other users how to implement your solution. That is quite different from degenerating into a tutorial.

Comment: It's not specific, because it requires to create a whole solution with many aspects. If you google you'll find things like [Create a form that contains a subform (a one-to-many form)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-ddf3822f-8aba-49cb-831a-1e74d6f5f06b), [Setting Filter in Subform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109977/setting-filter-in-subform), etc., etc.

Comment: It is not specific because there is no code, no error message, no attempt at a solution. If you don't know how to build basic functionality like form/subform and combobox, then really need to study an introductory book.