# Bound textbox in main form to lookup query in subform

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm working on a project that involves generating a rental and later being able to return to manage the rental in the future (i.e. return the rental, the bill for damages, etc.

I have a query that creates rentals with an auto number for the id. 
Another query creates a list of items for each rental - this query is associated with 2 subforms (one to initially list items in a rental, and one to later return to declare items returned/damaged, etc..)

To manage the rental, I have a form where I want to be able to scan a bar-code equivalent of a rental ID and pass the value to a subform to display the details query (table view) to be able to edit/process rental items. When the textbox is bound, it throws an error stating that I cant type in the field because it is autogenerated. If I leave the textbox unbound, how would I pass the value to the subform to be able to process the rental?

Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Filter in Subform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109977/setting-filter-in-subform)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a new unbound text box and a Search button next to it. The button will have code to filter your subform according value in this unbound text box where user types the ID.